# Flutter listview always scrolling to bottom when reverse is true

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-listview

Why I am using reverse is true, Its for achieving fetch messages from realtime database sorted by time added. after doing this, New messages at ToP and old messages lies down in listview. Everything works well, this is the condition I wanted. But The list view is always scrolling to bottom instead of lying on top.If user enters the page, he is will see old posts first, instead of new posts. Here is my ocde

```
return ListView.builder(
    controller: _scrollController,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    //physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemCount: nots.length,
    reverse: true,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.amber[50],
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              column(nots[index].title,nots[index].date,nots[index].body,nots[index].photourl),
              //column,
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
```

If I remove reverse: True. then old posts lies on top and new messages lies on bottom. But in this case listview is not scrolling to bottom. In short words, When I use both cases. Users can only see old posts first. But I want to see them new posts first.
[image]

Comment: Why not iterate through the messages in reverse order, and keep the list in normal order? So for example, within `itemBuilder: (context, index) {` start with `int reverseIndex = nots.length - 1 - index;` and then use `reverseIndex` instead of `index`.

Comment: Thanks Problem solved. This is the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

ListView `reverse: true` displays the List fed to it from the bottom. If you'd like for the ListView to start at the top, you'd need to sort the List to be displayed on the ListView instead.

Answer (score -1):

Simply, reverse the list before accessing it inside the `ListView.builder` and you won't need `shrinkWrap` and the `reversed` property of the `ListView.builder` anymore.

```
var revList = nots.reversed.toList();
return ListView.builder(
    controller: _scrollController,
    itemCount: revList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.amber[50],
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              column(revList[index].title, revList[index].date, revList[index].body, revList[index].photourl),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the explanation. Wouldn’t the `ListView.builder` still be required? Do you mean that those items won’t be needed _inside_ the `ListView.builder`?